# Dynamical System , Series : can't find the general terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, dynamical-systems

I have a dynamical system defined as follow :

$$V_{n+3} - 6V_{n+2} +12V_{n+1} - 8V_n = 8, ~ \mbox{with}~ V_0=V_1=V_2=1$$

I have to find $V_n$ = ?

So I began by solving this equation :

$$x^3 -6x^2 + 12x - 8 = 0$ <=> $(x-2)^3 = 0$ <=> $x= 2$$

But then I'd like to do :

$$V_n = \sum(\alpha_i*x_i^n))$$

but with $V_0 =V_1=V_2 = 1$ it seems kinda impossible ... Do you have an idea?

Comment: What does your textbook say when the characteristic equation has multiple roots?

Comment: I don't have a textbook , i'm learning by myself , but i have a hard time finding a good lecture on internet ....

But i don't really see where do you spot a multiple roots characteristic equation...

Comment: The roots of x3−6x2+12x−8=0 are 2, 2, 2. You showed this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica's `FindSequenceFunction` states that
$$V_n = \frac{1}{16} \left(9\ 2^n n^2-63\ 2^n n+63\ 2^{n+1}-128\right).$$
Once you have the formula, of course, it's an easy process to verify that it satisfies the recurrence relation.

For information on the mathematics behind this sort of thing, you might have a look at [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the pdf, it seems really well done...  :)

Comment: @Boo - The book is a classic!

Comment: And the title is in one word, with no capitalized letter...